# gvim regular expression match pair of words

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds

I would like a VIM regular expression for to find pairs of words optionally. They can be separated by other words, but they both must be on the same line.
For example, If I wanted to match open and close then these should match:

```
open foo close
open close
foo
```

and these should not match:

```
open foo
open
foo close
close
```

I have tried to use lookahead and lookbehind to match words, but I just can't seem to find the right combination.

I know how to do this for single characters, but words have got me completely lost.

Here's an attempt:

```
s/\(\(open\)\@=.*\(close\)\@=\)*
```

For the same thing but with 'a' and 'c' instead of 'open' and 'close' I can do this:

```
s/^\(a[^ac]*c\|[^ac]\)*$
```

This would select all of these lines (and a blank line):

```
acabcacabbbbcbbb
ac
abc
b
```

but wouldn't select

```
acbbc
ab
bc
a
c
```

This is the functionality I'm looking for, but with words.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Nachum

Edit:
I am working on an indent script, and this would've helped. Instead, I ended up searching and converting words to single letters. Then I used methods that I'm already familiar with to match the single characters. At least it shortens the code once the first conversion is done.

Comment: You should show your best efforts, even if they are not working perfectly. This will help people see what you were trying to do and let you know what you were doing wrong... also people like to see evidence that you attempted to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Updated with my own attempts. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Just search for this:

```
open.*close
```

Comment: This wouldn't match "foo" (a line without either open or close) as the OP expressed he would like to match.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
^((?!.*open|.*close).*|.*open.*close.*)$
```

Breaks down to:

`(?!.*open|.*close).*` - anything excluding open or close
or
`.*open.*close.*` - something including both an open and a close

I'm not familiar with vim, but from what you've shown I think you look like you'd be able to convert the syntax.